# getting error map is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which produces an error:

```
const List = ( items ) => {
  return items.map((item, key) => <div key={key}> {item.text}</div>);
}

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([{text:'john'}, {text:'smith'}]);
  return (
    <div>
      <List items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Error**: items.map is not a function

Anyone can explain in details why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `<Component />` syntax, your function component will receive a `props` argument, which wraps the properties that you bind to the component. You should be using `props.items`:

```
const List = (props) => {
  const {items}=props;
  return items.map((item, key) => <div key={key}> {item.text}</div>);
}
```

You could as well directly destructure the props argument:

```
const List = ({items}) => {
  return items.map((item, key) => <div key={key}> {item.text}</div>);
}
```

Another way would be to bind the function component call into the template:

```
<div>
  {List(items)}
</div>
```

By doing this, the `items` property wont be wrapped in a `props` object.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `<App>` conponent renders with the `<List items={items} />` element.
2. React calls the `List` component with `{items: [{text:'john'}, {text:'smith'}]}` as the props.
3. So, if you do:

   ```
   const List = ( props ) => {
      console.log(props)
   }
   ```

   You will see `{items: [{text:'john'}, {text:'smith'}]}`. So, we need to use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) here like:

   ```
   const List = ( {items} ) => {
      return items.map(({text}, key) => <div key={key}>{text}</div>);
   }
   ```

   to get the desired result. Or, you can put it in one line like:

   ```
   const List = ({items}) => items.map(({text},key) => <div key={key}>{text}</div>);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

"items" is a property and you need to use object destructor something like below.

```
const List = ({items}) => {
  return items.map((item, key) => <div key={key}> {item.text}</div>);
}
```